# Loop/Cycle through Subdirectories and determine file count in each

Tags: loops, powershell, powershell-3.0, subdirectory

I have the directory `E:\NugetRoot\NugetServer` where I need to cycle through the subdirectories on this path and within the packages folder within that subdirectory I need to count the files ending in `.nupkg` and output them to a cvs file named `d:\monitoring\NugetStatistics` and each time the script is run, it should append to the file.

1. Count the files ending in `.nupkg` in `"C:\NugetRoot\NugetServer\\**\Packages"` for each folder. (I need to Loop through the ** folders and count each file ending on `.nupkg`)
2. Output in `cvs` file with two columns: one showing the "**" folder name & the other showing the file count.

Comment: can be done but could you let us know what has been tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

First find all the `*.nupkg` files using Get-Childitem with the recurse flag to get all files in sub folders, then filter the results using a regex to exclude any where the final folder is not called Package. Then use another regex to extract the previous folder name, feed that in to a Group-Object to get the count and then into a Export-Csv which includes the append flag.

```
cd E:\NugetRoot\NugetServer
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.nupkg -Recurse | ? {
  $_.DirectoryName -match '\\Packages$'
} | % {
  $_.DirectoryName -Replace '^.*\\([^\\]+)\\Packages$', '$1'
} | Group-Object | Select Name, Count | Export-Csv outfile.csv -Append -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cd "C:\NugetRoot\NugetServer\\**\Packages"    
$a = Get-ChildItem -Name

foreach ($i in $a) {    
    $b = (Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Force -Include .nupkg  -Path $i | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name).Count
    $i + "`t" + $b    
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO and thanks for contributing. It is even more helpful if you explain what you have done and why you have done so. This way, the OP can actually learn something from your answer, rather than just copy/paste it and have no real clue what did the trick.

Comment: Here's what I have so far. It displays the server name, ProjectgroupID(or folder name), but get error for package count. Also, I am having trouble getting the average file size as well, I commented those out:

Comment: Here it is:$folders = gci C:\NuGetRoot\NugetServer -Directory
foreach($folder in $folders){
    @{ServerName=$env:COMPUTERNAME;
        ProjectGroupID = $folder.Name;
        NuGetPackageCount = (gci $folder.FullName\packages -Include '*.nupkg') | %{$_.Size}.Count;
        #AverageSize= Measure-Object (listof sizes) -Average

    } #| Export-Csv -Path c:\temp -NoTypeInformation -Append

}
Measure-Object -Average

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I have so far. It displays the server name, ProjectgroupID(or folder name), but get error for package count. Also, I am having trouble getting the average file size as well, I commented those out:

```
$folders = gci C:\NuGetRoot\NugetServer -Directory
foreach($folder in $folders){
    @{ServerName=$env:COMPUTERNAME;
        ProjectGroupID = $folder.Name;
        NuGetPackageCount = (gci $folder.FullName\packages -Include '*.nupkg') | %{$_.Size}.Count;
        #AverageSize= Measure-Object (listof sizes) -Average

    } #| Export-Csv -Path c:\temp -NoTypeInformation -Append

}
Measure-Object -Average
```